# No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

Warning: include(./app/TableGateways/PersonGateway.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/index.php on line 4

I would include a php file to my index.php on line 4 :

```
include('./app/TableGateways/PersonGateway.php');
```

I'm using a docker-compose with these containers :

```
version: '3.8'
services:

  server:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
      - ./app/:/app
    links:
      - php

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/php.dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/var/www/html/
    links:
      - db
```

You can look my php dockerfile :

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

COPY app/ var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

And my directory :

[current directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWz71.png)

Thank You for your help !! :)

I think it's probably my volumes organization, maybe the path...

Comment: What exactly is the problem... What is on line 4 in index.php?

Comment: On line 4 of my index.php file : include('./app/TableGateways/PersonGateway.php');

Comment: If your `index.php` is in the directory `app` I think you should remove the `./app` in your include. Its hard to say without seeing your directory layout

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Make sure to formulate a "question"; without it, it might be hard to answer it, as pointed out by @DieterKräutl, we don't understand your problem. You are missing a file in /var/www/html/. Can you reach this directory? Can you add your missing file to it?